# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js) - while trying to run npm run dev for laravel mix

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I'm trying to compile my css and js thru laravel mix but this error always pops up, hope someone can help. I've tried npm install a bunch of babel stuff, deleting node_modules and running npm install again, but no cigar :(

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.1
3 info using node@v13.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~predev: capstone2@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~dev: capstone2@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Earl\Documents\earl-diaz\projects\capstone2\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Earl\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\composer;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\xampp\php;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\adb;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\xampp\php;C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
9 verbose lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~dev: CWD: C:\Users\Earl\Documents\earl-diaz\projects\capstone2
10 silly lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle capstone2@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: capstone2@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid capstone2@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Earl\Documents\earl-diaz\projects\capstone2
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v13.1.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error capstone2@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the capstone2@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

I've pretty much installed all there is to install but it still wont work. Here's the package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "capstone2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "<p align=\"center\"><img src=\"https://res.cloudinary.com/dtfbvvkyp/image/upload/v1566331377/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\"></p>",
  "main": "webpack.mix.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gitlab.com/fael_/capstone2.git"
  },
  "author": "earl diaz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/fael_/capstone2/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/fael_/capstone2#readme",
  "keywords": []
}
```

Comment: Please add your package.json file

Comment: Did you check if the babel-loader folder alredy exists under node_modules ?
If it exists you probably need to downgrade the version

"babel-core": "^6.26.0"
"babel-loader": "^7.1.4"
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"

Check this link https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8599

Comment: tried those already, still gives the same err :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I just didn't have to use laravel mix after all. The new versions of laravel just doesn't require you to use it often.